# How to distribute credits between workers?

Tags: payable, statistics

I have just started mining. I have a miner composed by 3 workers. Each worker belongs to a different person. When I'll finalise a block I will receive a payout. I would like to know how to distribite this payout,  in an equitable way, to each of the 3 workers. Where can I see how much each worker contributed to finish 1 block of the wallet / miner?

I run claymore miner , ethdcrminer64
I took instructions from your site, under Claymores Miner paragraph, I run a bat as you explain, and i use eu1.ethpool.org:3333

Comment: Consider re-phrasing your question adding more details.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run a pool. What pool software are you running or are you directly submitting work to your node (such as Parity or `geth`)?

Comment: I run claymore miner , ethdcrminer64 I took instructions from your site, under Claymores Miner paragraph, I run a bat as you explain, and i use eu1.ethpool.org:3333

Comment: Not sure whose site you're referring to. Anyway, if you want to distribute the payout for ethpool based on submitted work (I'm assuming you found two friends to mine with you), you can set up a pool that mines to ethpool. Your own pool can track how much work each person contributed. Alternately, you can have each worker mine to a separate address on ethpool. It will just take longer to find a block.